# Error with registration in the pset9 cs5(unexpected exceptions)

Tags: javascript, python, html, cs50

> "registering user succeeds application raised an exception (see the
> log for more details)" "registration rejects duplicate username
> application raised an exception (see the log for more details)"

idk what to do :((

**REGISTER.HTML:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Password (again)" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**INDEX.HTML:**

```
% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Portfolio
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Shares</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>TOTAL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <td>{{ sum_totals | usd }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            {% for summary in summaries %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ summary.symbol }}</td>
                    <td>{{ summary.company }}</td>
                    <td>{{ summary.sum_of_shares }}</td>
                    <td>{{ summary.price | usd }}</td>
                    <td>{{ summary.total | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">CASH</td>
                <td>{{ owned_cash | usd }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**APPY.PY (register):**

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "POST":

        if not (username := request.form.get("username")):
            return apology("MISSING USERNAME")

        if not (password := request.form.get("password")):
            return apology("MISSING PASSWORD")

        if not (confirmation := request.form.get("confirmation")):
            return apology("PASSWORD DON'T MATCH")

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;", username)

        # Ensure username not in database
        if len(rows) != 0:
            return apology(f"The username '{username}' already exists. Please choose another name.")

        # Ensure first password and second password are matched
        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("password not matched")

        # Insert username into database
        id = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?);",
                        username, generate_password_hash(password))

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = id

        flash("Registered!")

        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

If someone wants to see the entire doc, write to `ambrosinogiuliana1@gmail.com` .
Its the last exercise that I need to be able to finish the course :(((

> "Complete the implementation of register in such a way that it allows
> a user to register for an account via a form.

```
Require that a user input a username, implemented as a text field whose name is username. Render an apology if the user’s input is blank or the username already exists.
Require that a user input a password, implemented as a text field whose name is password, and then that same password again, implemented as a text field whose name is confirmation. Render an apology if either input is blank or the passwords do not match.
Submit the user’s input via POST to /register.
INSERT the new user into users, storing a hash of the user’s password, not the password itself. Hash the user’s password with generate_password_hash Odds are you’ll want to create a new template (e.g., register.html) that’s quite similar to login.html.
```

> Once you’ve implemented register correctly, you should be able to
> register for an account and log in (since login and logout already
> work)! And you should be able to see your rows via phpLiteAdmin or
> sqlite3."

:(

Comment: Does it run correctly/without errror when you run it locally? What kind of "more details" does the log provide? (If memory serves it includes a traceback which will show what line is producing error).

Comment: The log says:
"sending POST request to /register
exception raised in application: RuntimeError: no such column: company" and
"sending POST request to /register
exception raised in application: RuntimeError: no such column: company " doesn't work locally either :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in index route of app.py (not shown). index.html indicates a variable called "company" here `<td>{{ summary.company }}</td>`. In the index function there is a sql SELECT to get users stock holdings. THere is no column named "company" in that table.